# How to remove variable from the server memory?

Tags: node.js, pci-compliance

I have an nodejs application that required to compliance to PCI/DSS standard.

Example :

```
let number = "91029039102930193092"
```

How can I remove it effectively from memory or V8 Garbage Collector (GC)?

Can I do this: `number = ""` to reset it to empty string?

Comment: Yes you can do `number = ""` or `delete number;`

Comment: @ponury-kostek that wouldn't necessarily remove it from memory immediately.

Comment: Where is the variable declared? If it's within a function, the variable will be garbage collected when the function finish executing. If it's global scope, it may stay in the memory throughout the lifetime of the nodejs app.

Comment: You might also want to take note that micro optimization can be bad. You should let `v8` handle the garbage collection. The typical things you look out for are cyclic referenced objects that can possibly cause memory leak.

Comment: Forcing the variable to be garbage-collected *probably* doesn't help with PCI, because it's still in memory for some length of time.  You may want to post another question explaining what you're trying to do and which PCI requirement you're dealing with - there may be a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run node with `--expose_gc` flag. In your code then you can do

```
number = "";
```

or

```
delete number;
```

and after this force gc

```
global.gc();
```

This will give you possibility to immediately free memory

```
delete number;
global.gc();
```

and safer way

```
number = undefined;
global.gc();
```